# Override custom newQuery() in Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent

For my **Deal** model, I'm using `newQuery()` to ensure that only unexpired and approved deals are ever queried. However, a few cases have come up where I don't want these two conditions to be in effect, and I want to query all deals.

What can I do?

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true) {
    return parent::newQuery()->where('end_date', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->where('approved', 1);
}
```

*Note: I'm not using Laravel, I'm just using the Eloquent library via Composer.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for conditional clauses - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#conditional-clauses

and some examples:

http://themsaid.com/laravel-query-conditions-20160425/